# What is the cleanest way to convert javascript "almost arrays" into "arrays"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been playing around with JavaScript for the past few months and found it to be really refreshing after not using it for many years.

That said, one thing in particular that really bothers me is its' inconsistancies in how it describes "[]" construct.

In particular, I am used to having Arrays have a "map" function, but many things that are "[]"-enclosed do not support map, but often support a synonym, and sometimes don't at all.

Examples:

1. document.getElementById('my-div').children

Has no mappability at all and each time I need to map over it, I have to resort to for loops.

2. document.querySelectorAll('#my-div *')

Has `forEach :: callback -> undefined`

Unlike map, does not return an array, so chaining transformations is "strange" because in addition to mapping over the object, you also have to store the results in an array to continue.

This means the following won't work.

```
(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll('#my-div *').forEach((divObject) => {
        console.log('found a ' + divObject.tagName + '.');
        return divObject;
    }).forEach((divObject) => {
        console.log('more transformations on ' + divObject.tagName + '.');
        return divObject;
    });
})();
```

but this will:

```
(() => {
    var children = [];

    document.querySelectorAll('#my-div *').forEach((divObject) => {
        children.push(divObject);
    });

    children.map((divObject) => {
        console.log('found a ' + divObject.tagName + '.');
        return divObject;
    }).map((divObject) => {
        console.log('more transformations on ' + divObject.tagName + '.');
        return divObject;
    });
})();
```

But the copying of elements "one by one" inside a forEach is just extra work that serves no real purpose, and generally should be optimized out before publishing code like this, as it is a detriment to performance for no good reason.

3. jQuery's map works correctly. eg `$('#my-div *')` has a `map :: callback -> array that supports map operation`. So it can be chained as expected.

**The Question**:

Is there a cleaner way to overcome the inconsistancy of array-like interfaces(things that appear to be "Arrays" but do not support Array.prototype.map) than having to do the first-iteration using a for loop, pushing the contents, only after that knowing that it behaves the way you think it behaves?

Comment: `var properArray = [...arrayLike]` or `var properArray = Array.from(arrayish)`

Comment: That seems much more efficient than manually copying it one by one. All I had to do was `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]'))` and now I can map ^_^. Can you make it its own answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Dmitry as far as "effiiency", there's not much difference; those two approaches  that Redu mentioned will perform the element-by-element transfer too.

Comment: @Pointy Are they really that incompatible that they have to be explicitly marshalled one by one to be converted? I mean they both have length, and map is only an abstraction over a for loop that keeps track of the elements it passes by and returns them at the end... If that is the case, I should just pre-compile everything into for loops to avoid wasteful conversion just to access an interface that can be used without requiring the conversion(you can simulate the behavior perfectly with for loops)...

Comment: Well both the `[... arrayLike]` and `Array.from()` techniques must explicitly create a new array; that's what they fundamentally mean. Now, on the other hand, using `Array.prototype.map.apply(arrayLike, callback)` does not have to make a copy.

Comment: OK that makes more sense, thanks pointy :) It's a bit more complicated than it could be but but it expresses exactly what I want to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all exotic arrays like node lists etc if they are iterable you can safely do like

`var properArray = [...arrayLike]` or `var properArray = Array.from(arrayish)`

or you can even do like

```
var properarray = Array(arrayish.length),
              i = 0;
for (var key of arrayish) while i < arrayish.length properArray[i++] = arrayish(key);
```

If you have an object like

```js
var o = {prop_1:"one thing",
         prop_2:"another thing"},
    a = [];

o[Symbol.iterator] = function* (){
                       var oks = Object.keys(this);
                       for (var key of oks) yield this[key]
                     }
a = [...o];
console.log(a);
```

you can make it iterable and convert it into an array the same way;

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid making a copy of an array by using `.apply`:

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

Array.prototype.map.apply(nodeList, function(node) {
  // do something with node
});
```

(Obviously the call to `.map()` will itself make a new array, but that's going to happen anyway.)

Comment: Yeah I can understand that it is going to make a new array regardless due to nature of map, which is to return something you can continue mapping onto, which requires a new array. But it's nice to be able to do this.

Comment: Use `forEach` if you don't want the mapped array.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is: **avoid chaining**.

Converting to array and mapping just to be able to chain `forEach` is a waste.

Instead, just store the NodeList in a variable.

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('*');
nodes.forEach(node =>
  console.log('found a ' + node.tagName + '.'))
nodes.forEach(node =>
  console.log('more transformations on ' + node.tagName + '.'));
```

Note NodeList weren't iterable until DOM4.